# I can't get a folder and camera to read

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with this code. It gives me the errors below.

Error:

- GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

This is a code to compare the images present in a folder and the image provided by my webcam.

It will be used to validate the compared images in order to launch actions on Arduino electronics.
Can you help me?

```
import cv2

#Charger l'image depuis le dossier
image_path = "/Users/appia-slc/Desktop/SynologyDrive/Projet perso/Projet_python/ReconnaissanceImage/Image"
print ("ok")
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
print ("ok1")



# Initialiser la capture vidéo depuis la webcam
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
print("ok2")


# Lire les images de la webcam en continu
while True: 
    ret, frame = capture.read()

# Redimensionner l'image de la webcam pour correspondre à la taille de l'image chargée
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

# Comparer les deux images
    difference = cv2.absdiff(image, frame_resized)
    difference_gray = cv2.cvtColor(difference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, difference_thresh = cv2.threshold(difference_gray,30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Afficher les images
    cv2.imshow("Image originale", image)
    cv2.imshow("Image de la webcam", frame_resized)
    cv2.imshow("Différence", difference_thresh)

# Quitter la boucle si la touche 'q' est pressée
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Libérer la capture vidéo et fermer les fenêtres
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to change the name of the folder having seen some questions on forums.

Comment: `cv2.imread` requires the exact path of the image including the image name, not just the folder path. Eg. `image = cv2.imread(image_path + '/image.jpg')

Comment: welcome. complete traceback required. [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.